# How to resolve relative path from JavaScript within MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

This is the url which i am trying to hit from within .js file which contains knockout related function:

self.followAction = $.resolvePath("/People/Follow?uid=" + data.UserId);
here People is the controller and Follow is the action method, on button click, i want to send userId along so i have written this.

To resolve relative path from within javascript, i have written this function

```
// Fix for resolving relative paths from within js scripts
$.resolvePath = function(url)
{
var path = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
if (path != '/') return path + url;
 return url;
};
```

But, on button click, i am getting this error: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
the url which it is trying is :

```
localhost:44305/People/@Request.ApplicationPath/People/Follow?uid=8
```

I have came to know that razor code is not interpreted within js files.
so, i have put this function inside a partial view :

```
   $.resolvePath = function(url)
    {
      var path = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
      if (path != '/') return path + url;
       return url;
     };
```

I have tried calling this directly in layout head's section like this:

```
 <head>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("VirtualPathFix"); }
 </head>
```

but then error starts showing:

```
 $.resolveurl: function is not defined
```

if i put this function directly in the people.js file in scripts folder, then no error but then on follow button click,http 404 error with url passed is :

```
 localhost:44305/People/@Request.ApplicationPath/People/Follow?uid=8
```

can anyone help me out.feeling lost

I have tried to use window.baseUrl in header on view page as suggested by darin:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
   </script>
```

but my people.js file is unable to fetch this property so error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.baseUrl is not a function on line18 in people.js file. Can anyone tell me what are other things to try.
```

Comment: Have you put it in `DOM` `ready`?

Comment: no, i think if i put code in .js file then razor will not identify this function dont know where to put code now frustated @ParthTrivedi

Answer (score 4):

You could prepare this url in your Razor template:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
    </script>
</head>
```

Now in your js files you could use this variable `window.baseUrl` You no longer need this `$.resolvePath` function.

Comment: Let me try thnxx for the help sir

Comment: public ActionResult Follow(int uid)
            {
                repository.Follows(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), uid);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "People");
            } but it is not hitting this action method what should be problem now. Now url sent is: //localhost:44305/People/Follow?uid=8 but same / Error Requested URL: /People/Follow. if u can help me much needed @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: Then you probably have some issues with your routing definition.

Comment: What url do you expect to get?

Comment: In this case your routing definition might be wrong. Hard to know from the information provided in your question.

Comment: data-bind="visible: !isFollowed && !isOwnProfile, attr: { href: followAction }">Follow</a> this is the button from which this invokes:  self.followAction = window.baseUrl("/People/Follow?uid=" + data.UserId);

Comment: By routing, I meant server side routes. From what I understand you are trying to call server side action that is supposed to listen at the `/People/Follow` endpoint.

Comment: yupp exactly it should behave normally i have not touched routing just simple code. data should have reached action method but dont know why its not @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: Do you have a `PeopleController` with an action named `Follow`? Notice that your controller class should be called `PeopleController`, not `People`. Is this the case?

Comment: public class PeopleController : Controller
     {
      private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public virtual ApplicationDbContext DataContext
    {
      get { return _context; }
    }
     public PeopleController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    } this is the starting code

Comment: Are you using areas?

Comment: Is your `Follow` action accessible with the GET verb? It doesn't have an `[HttpPost]` attribute on it, right?

Comment: got it got it got it very very much thnxx for the help sir @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: dont know but i am now getting Uncaught TypeError: window.baseUrl is not a function for the first time it was running fine @Darin Dimitrov sir